# How to change the Schema name and move the table into another schema?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a bit problem while changing the schema name. My problem is I have a table1 with schema1 and there is another schema called schema2. So how can I move the table1 in schema2?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ALTER SCHEMA schema2
    TRANSFER schema1.table1;
GO
```

[Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173423.aspx).

Comment: Hi,  I am getting an error while executing it.....................                                              Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Cannot find the object 'table1', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

Comment: You may not have adequate permissions to execute 'ALTER SCHEMA' on the database you are modifying table schemas on. Check the 'Permissions' section in the referenced article for more information.